How to display item count in menu of magento2 admin?
in the magento2 admin side, I want to display the records count if I have 5 records in operations the 5 will be displayed in order in the menu, I have multiple items in the menu. Each record will show the count respectively. I have the main menu in the admin side menu, which has various sub-menus, I want to show the count with all sub-menu items respectively.


I tested this code and it worked fine.
what i did is change the core file for testing purpose.
You can override the file in app/desgin
Your override path will be
/app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Backend/templates/menu.phtml

Navigate to this file
vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/menu.phtml

and copy this whole code and paste in there
    <!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

// Order Count
$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection');
$orderCount = $orderCollection->getSize();

// Invoice Count
$invoiceCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection');
$invoiceCount = $invoiceCollection->getSize();

// Shipment Count
$shipmentCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Collection');
$shipmentCount = $shipmentCollection->getSize();
?>


<nav data-mage-init='{"globalNavigation": {}}' class="admin__menu">
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderNavigation($block->getMenuModel(), 0, 12) ?>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function appendCount(menuItemClass, count) {
                const menuItemSpan = document.querySelector('li.' + menuItemClass + ' a span');
                if (menuItemSpan) {
                    const countElement = document.createElement('span');
                    countElement.textContent = '(' + count + ')';
                    menuItemSpan.parentNode.insertBefore(countElement, menuItemSpan.nextSibling);
                }
            }
            
            var orderCount = <?php echo $orderCount; ?>;
            appendCount('item-sales-order', orderCount);
            
            var invoiceCount = <?php echo $invoiceCount; ?>;
            appendCount('item-sales-invoice', invoiceCount);
            
            var shipmentCount = <?php echo $shipmentCount; ?>;
            appendCount('item-sales-shipment', shipmentCount);
        });
    });
</script>

Result is like this


@mateen is it working for you, if yes please accept answer. Thanks
